# How to fill area between two circle in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I want to fill area between two circle in canvas
[image]

this is my ondraw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radarRadius / 3, mPaintCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, 3 * radarRadius / 7, mPaintCircle);
}
```

Comment: Did you try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411560/how-to-fill-area-between-two-circle-in-canvas/38411626#38411626)?

Comment: I am not able to see any circle after drawing it.

Comment: Did you fill the `canvas` with any color?

Comment: I tried canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE); is it right?

Comment: Just set a background color to the view on which you have overridden `onDraw` method.

Comment: its not working for api bellow 19

Comment: try disabling Hardware Acceleration for your view by `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` then it would work.

Comment: Can you also accept my answer by clicking tick mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two circular paths and clip the canvas like this:

```
Path outerPath = new Path();
outerPath.addCircle(centerX, centerY, outerRadius, Direction.CW);
Path innerPath = new Path();
innerPath.addCircle(centerX, centerY, innerRadius, Direction.CW);
canvas.clipPath(outerPath);
canvas.clipPath(innerPath, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
```

Along with that disable Hardware Acceleration on the view:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following simple rule :)

[image: Two nested circles]

**Sample Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Two Circles</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        var cx = 100
        var cy = 100
        var r1 = 80
        var r2 = 60

        // outer circle
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red'
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, r1, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill()

        // inner circle
        ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, r2, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill()
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```